# Michigan Projection with GDAL or FWTools

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, fwtools

Has anyone come across a specific projection for Michigan, specifically:
`NAD_1983_CORS96_StatePlane_Michigan_South_FIPS_2113_Ft_Intl`

When I look at spatialreference.org I do not find any instance of the projection, so I can locate the ESPG code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There dosen't appear to be a EPSG for that.  It seems to be ESRI specific:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisexplorer/2500/sdk/componenthelp/index.html#/NAD1983CORS96StatePlaneMichiganSouthFIPS2113IntlFt_Property/000300000znr000000/

You can get a WKT, prj etc. file from here:

http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/102690/